# Expose filter in block to show results on view page

Tags: views

I want to make custom search block on home page, in header region. I'm using Exposed filter block in Views module, but results on the page are shown just below the block, in header. I want results of the search to be shown on the other page, like regular search do. Is there a way to achieve this. I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: Have you tried put exposed filter to a block, so you can assign the block to any region you want. And search result in content region. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I assigned my exposed block to header region but it shows results just bellow exposed box.

What I want to achieve is to have search box just like core Drupal search box but use Views modul and exposed filter to make something like that.

Problem is that with exposed filter I didn't find the way to make search results show on other page (to redirect results to other page rather than to show them bellow exposed search box).

Tnx!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a page view using filter you want.
Step 1) Enable the block in your View

[image]

Step 2) Put the exposed filter block where you want it to be
[image]

Step 3 ) Test the result
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I cannot believe it was so simple. I was trying almost everything but the biggest mistake was that I was always starting with block and not with page itself.

Comment: What's defining that the results go in the content region? You left that out.

Answer (score 2):

One more thing for people using "Content pane" display in views. You need to set "Use Panel path: Yes" in order to fix this issue.